# RegExp: How to find lines that don't end with some pattern?

Tags: regex, end-of-line

I have a log-file. Most of the lines in it ends with some sub-string (for example it `0.02`). I can filter that lines with pattern `0\.02$`. But how I can filter rest lines, other than ending with `0.02`?

Comment: do you use some tool? or some programming language? there could be easier way.

Comment: Wait, do you mean get lines that DON'T end with `0.02`

Comment: `grep -v '0\.02$' my.log`

Comment: Why not just invert the search? Match against the pattern but reject those lines instead of allowing them? (See, for example, `grep -v`)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Yes, you are right. Looks like my poor English obfuscated my question :) I'l try fix it.

Comment: sed has the `d` command which removes matching lines. So something like this `sed '/0\.02$/d' logfile` might work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\b0\.02)$
```

Answer (score 4):

Find end-of-line, then look back to check if your string is not there:

```
.(?<!0\.02)$
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this would be a problem (or a benefit) in the asker's scenario, but having the leading dot means this pattern would not match an empty line, which technically meets the requirement of not ending with "0.02".

Comment: Some GREP dialects don't like to look for just-a-location, hence the period.

Comment: @Jongware, your statement about some grep dialects not liking to look for just-a-location is true about the regex searching in NetBeans 7.4.  Your solution worked there.

Comment: @idclaar: I know this to be true for InDesign and for TextPad (Windows). TextWrangler (Mac), on the other hand, has no problem using only `^` or `$` in find-and-replaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using grep then grep has `-v` switch just for that:

```
 egrep -v "(^|[^0-9])0\.02$" my.log
```